# How can I add a tokenized parameter to a web.config file so it shows up in SetParameters.xml?

Tags: .net-4.0, tfs, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I need to be able to add a single parameter in the AppSettings section to the SetParameters.xml file that is generated during a TFS build for deploying using MSDeploy.  Currently only connection strings get tokenized.

How can I add a key from the AppSettings section?

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer to my own question.  The link below is a great post on how to add custom parameters to be filled in during webdeploy deployments.

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/07/web-deploy-parameterization-in-action.html

Comment: Here is some additional MSDN info on the above solution: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Here is another good reference doc from IIS.net.
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/722/reference-for-the-web-application-package/